# Поиск фрагмента текста между двумя словами

Tags: delphi

Подскажите, как реализовать процедуру поиска фрагмента текста между двумя заданными словами и добавлением найденного фрагмента в **memo1**?

Например, нужно найти все строки, которые находятся между **public** и **end;**

```
public
line1:integer;
line2:string;
line3:real:
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Извиняюсь за никропостинг но вдруг кто наткнется на данный пример, PosEx ведет счет символов не с 0 а с 1 потому пример будет выдавать пустую строку, правильно Pos1 := PosEx(First, WhereLower, 1);

Answer (score 0):

Ну, например, особо не заморачиваясь, так:

(Данный пример выведет весь текст, находящийся между "First_word" и "Second_word")

```
uses StrUtils;
...

function get_stext(First, Second, Where: string): string;
var
  Pos1, Pos2: Integer;
  WhereLower: string;
begin
  First := LowerCase(First);
  Second := LowerCase(Second);
  WhereLower := LowerCase(Where);
  Assert(Length(WhereLower) = Length(Where));

  Pos1 := PosEx(First, WhereLower, 0);
  Pos2 := PosEx(Second, WhereLower, Pos1);
  Result := Copy(Where, Pos1 + Length(First), Pos2 - Pos1 - Length(First));
end;

var st: string;
begin
  st := get_stext('first_word', 'second_word',
    '123123 First_word <some text> 123123    elseFDFsdf  0123123 Second_word');
  ShowMessage(st);  // вывод " <some text> 123123    elseFDFsdf  0123123 "
end;
```

Comment: Я отформатировал код, для приличия (пользовался [этим style guide](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10280#3.0)), если не возражаете. Assert добавил, потому что не уверен, что все будет работать. Если бы было `UpperCase` — оно бы, предположительно, сломалось на немецкой локали с «ß» («ß» в верхнем регистре, за редкостью «ẞ», традиционно переводится в «SS»). Возможно, подобная ситуация имеет место и с `LowerCase`.

Я бы, пожалуй, обошелся в духе `TRegEx.Matches(Where, 'first_word\s+(.+)\s+second_word', [roIgnoreCase, roMultiLine])` (или как оно там).

Comment: Я не против совершенных действий, @drdaeman. Assert здесь и правда к месту, но я просто решил не углубляться особо в подробности...а так, спасибо.

Comment: друзья, не хочу показаться снобом, но можно ли данное действие (по поиску текста) реализовать не введение новой функции, а уже существующими методами? 
Допустим, есть поле memo, куда мы загрузили наш файл. И как из него выдрать кусок текста и поместить его в поле memo2 (как помещать - знаю, а как выделять то, что надо по вопросу - нет)